# SharePoint 2013 connecting with site-mailbox

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, site-mailboxes

I have activated the site mailbox feature on the farm and on the site collection:
I also created a security group for the mailbox users and after doing that, I get this:

Your SharePoint Server configuration is not supported
Your organization's SharePoint Server configuration is not supported. Please contact your system administrator for more information.

Correlation ID: 87bdf49b-f306-903f-1e78-06708ea83ce8, Error Code 101

Mon Jan 14 2013 16:26:52 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

I use exchange 2010 and Outlook 2010, is this a problem?
How can I get this right, can you provide me the steps?

Answer (score 2):

Site Mailboxes require 2013 of everything - Exchange, Outlook and SharePoint.

Comment: Yep, one of the features readily available on O365 which will take a while for uptake for on-prem SP2013 installs.

Comment: Plus a very cool feature.

Answer (score -1):

check his url to do this step by step
http://www.scinaptic.com/support/0109.html